# NSData AES trigger unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

[I use a AES library from github NSData+AES by nicerobot's objc](https://github.com/nicerobot/objc/tree/master/NSData)

My codes are below :

-- `AESLib.h`--

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

@interface AESLib : NSObject
-(NSData *) encodeAES:(NSData *) argSource;
@end
```

-- `AESLib.m` --

```
-(NSData *) encodeAES:(NSData *) argSource
{
    NSString APIV1_AES_KEY = @"//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"; // 24 char
    NSString APIV1_AES_IV = @"//BBBBBBBBBBBBBB";  // 16 char
    NSData *key = [NSData dataWithBytes:APIV1_AES_KEY.UTF8String length:strlen(APIV1_AES_KEY.UTF8String)];
    NSData *iv = [NSData dataWithBytes:APIV1_AES_IV.UTF8String length:strlen(APIV1_AES_IV.UTF8String)];

    NSData *encData;
    @try {
        encData = [argSource encrypt:key withInitial:iv andPadding:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding];
        // Error Here
        return encData;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception : %@", [exception reason]);
    }

    return nil;
}
```

//Error

```
> XCode trigger error 2013-10-22 16:15:58.206 Aessample[2913:c07]
> -[NSConcreteMutableData encrypt:withInitial:andPadding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7523300 2013-10-22 16:15:58.207
> Aessample[2913:c07] Exception : -[NSConcreteMutableData
> encrypt:withInitial:andPadding:]: unrecognized selector sent to
> instance 0x7523300
```

Why this error happen?

--- Add to NSMutableString

Thank you NSMutableString.

I did tried again likewise your answers, but my code triggers still same errors.

Help again NSMutableString plz.

Comment: You're doing `#import <NSData+AES.h>` in your `AESLib.m`? I haven't touched that code since i posted it a few years ago. I'll try to make some time to test it with the latest tools.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the category files and add them again checking the target.